# SP2013: Adding commas to text fields

Tags: 2013, jquery, edit-form, newform

There's a lot of threads about getting rid of commas, but I want more commas.

On the NewItem and EditItem screens, I have some number and currency textboxes.  My users are entering values in the millions and often typing the wrong number of zeroes.  I know you can accomplish this with some jQuery, but how would I do that on a SharePoint page?

The ViewList screens are fine; SharePoint knows these are number or currency columns and *displays* them fine -- we only need to show them during editing.

Comment: Why not use the JQuery that you have on NewForm and EditForm? Are you facing any issue in that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a web part to the edit item form which has your custom jQuery script.

Click on the List, then in the ribbon click Form web parts, then Default Edit Form

On the Default Edit Form, add your script editor or content editor web part linking to your script.